# Unknown error in maven pom.xml when using intelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

so I recently installed maven in my pc. Did a little maven project with the guide of an online course in Udemy but I didn't get to finish it. My problem here is when I try to open maven in IntelliJ, pom.xml looks like this and I'm scared that this might cause a problem when I start another project on web dev using Java, SpringBoot, and RestAPI. I'm new to this so I'm not sure what to fix and make sure I will not face any errors. Thank you so much and looking forward to your helpful response.

[image: Screenshot of error in pom.xml inside IntelliJ]

Comment: Did you rename a folder? Try reopening it

Comment: Look like you have an empty `pom.xml` file. try to fill it with a valid XML tag for Maven's pom file. You can google it.

Answer (score 1):

It can be known from the error message that the reason for this error is because you did not add a constraint file for the xml file, so IDEA is prompting you to add a constraint space for the xml file.

You should check the constraint format of maven's pom.xml file and add it to your pom.xml file.

Another thing to know is that IDEA will use the built-in maven by default instead of the maven you downloaded. If you want to use the maven you downloaded, you should go to the settings to modify the maven configuration. (Of course you can use maven that comes with IDEA).